# how to know if my home is under negative pressure?

Tags: hvac, sealing, air-quality, air-leaks

I see dust under the baseboard but not much. And also, sometime I can smell "crawlspace" like smell but I am not very sure.

How to technically test the air pressure in home?  Even more, how to technically test the air flow in home?

Comment: Do you have forced air heating or cooling?  If you don't,there cannot possibly be a pressure differential in your house.

Comment: I don't have forced air heating. But I am guessing leaking duct could cause negative pressure. And I'd like to understand when range hood, bathroom exhaust fan are running, what will the air flow be like. I didn't see any fresh air intake vent yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you want to use or rent a manometer.

[image]

I suggest reading this article ( http://contractingbusiness.com/archive/how-measure-building-pressures ) as it details the differences in levels room to room and what the ideal pressure should be in vented and non vented areas, ie kitchen/bathroom as opposed to bed/living room.

As for the dust under the baseboards, that can be due to improper cleaing during construction of the dwelling.